# firebase Data Snapshot is not working in android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-maps

I have spent Hours on this...pls help

Here i have provided the code of the activity which uses firebase, googlesdk api.
Basically i wanted to make uber for ambulances but due to many errors or no responses the code dosent seem to work despite thw logic being right. It would be great if this is solved. Thank you

CustomerMapActivity
'

public class CustomerMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
Location mLastLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

private Button mLogout,mRequest,mSettings,mHistory;
private LatLng pickupLocation;
private Boolean requestBol = false;
private Marker pickupMarker;

private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

private String destination;

private LatLng destinationLatlng;

private RatingBar mRatingBar;

private LinearLayout mDriverInfo;

private TextView mDriverName, mDriverPhone, mDriverCar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_map);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    destinationLatlng = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);

    mDriverInfo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.driverInfo);

    mDriverName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.driverName);
    mDriverPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.driverPhone);
    mDriverCar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.driverCar);

    mRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request);
    mSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
    mRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    mHistory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.history);
    mLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);



    mLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerMapActivity.this, Welcome_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }

    });


    mRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(requestBol){
                endRide();


            }else {
            }
            requestBol = true;
            String userId=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customerRequest");
            GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
            geoFire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

            pickupLocation = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            pickupMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pickupLocation).title("Pickup Here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.patient)));

            mRequest.setText("Getting Your Ambulance...");

            getClosestDriver();
        }
    });


    mSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(CustomerMapActivity.this,CustomerSettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }

    });


    mHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(CustomerMapActivity.this,HistoryActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("customerOrDriver","Customers");
            startActivity(intent);
            return;

        }
    });




}

private int radius=1;
private Boolean driverFound = false;
private String driverFoundID;

GeoQuery geoQuery;


private void getClosestDriver(){
    DatabaseReference driverLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("driversAvailable");

    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(driverLocation);
    geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(pickupLocation.latitude, pickupLocation.longitude), radius);
    geoQuery.removeAllListeners();

    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            if (!driverFound && requestBol){
                DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(key);
                mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                            // Map<String, Object> driverMap = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            if (driverFound){
                                return;
                            }


                            driverFound = true;
                            driverFoundID = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                            DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID).child("customerRequest");
                            String customerId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            HashMap map = new HashMap();
                            map.put("customerRideId", customerId);
                            map.put("destination", destination);
                            map.put("destinationLat", destinationLatlng.latitude);
                            map.put("destinationLng", destinationLatlng.longitude);
                            driverRef.updateChildren(map);

                            getDriverLocation();
                            getDriverInfo();
                            getHasRideEnded();
                            mRequest.setText("Looking for Driver's Location....");
                        }

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
            if (!driverFound)
            {
                radius++;
                getClosestDriver();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
    /*private void getClosestDriver(){
        DatabaseReference driverLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("driversAvailable");
        GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(driverLocation);
        geoQuery=  geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(pickupLocation.latitude,pickupLocation.longitude), radius);
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                if(!driverFound && requestBol) {
                    driverFound = true;
                    driverFoundID = key;
                    DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID).child("customerRequest");
                    String customerId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();
                    map.put("customerRideId",customerId);
                    map.put("destination",destination);
                    map.put("destinationLat",destinationLatlng.latitude);
                    map.put("destinationLng",destinationLatlng.longitude);
                    driverRef.updateChildren(map);
                    getDriverLocation();
                    getHasRideEnded();
                    mRequest.setText("Looking for Ambulance Location...");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                if (!driverFound)
                {
                    radius++;
                    getClosestDriver();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }*/
private Marker mDriverMarker;
private DatabaseReference driverLocationRef;
private ValueEventListener driverLocationRefListener;
private void getDriverLocation(){
    driverLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("driversWorking").child(driverFoundID).child("l");
    driverLocationRefListener=driverLocationRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && requestBol){
                List<Object> map=(List<Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                double LocationLat = 0;
                double LocationLng = 0;
                // mRequest.setText("Ambulance Found");
                if(map.get(0)!= null){
                    LocationLat = Double.parseDouble(map.get(0).toString());
                }
                if(map.get(1)!= null){
                    LocationLng = Double.parseDouble(map.get(1).toString());
                }
                LatLng driverLatLng = new LatLng(LocationLat, LocationLng);
                if(mDriverMarker!=null){
                    mDriverMarker.remove();
                }
                Location loc1 = new Location("");
                loc1.setLatitude(pickupLocation.latitude);
                loc1.setLongitude(pickupLocation.longitude);

                Location loc2 = new Location("");
                loc2.setLatitude(driverLatLng.latitude);
                loc2.setLongitude(driverLatLng.longitude);

                float distance = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
                if(distance<100){
                    mRequest.setText("Ambulance Arrived");
                }else{
                    int dis = (int)distance/1000;
                    mRequest.setText("Ambulance Found: "+ String.valueOf(dis)+ " Kms away...");

                }

                mDriverMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLatLng).title("Your Ambulance").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ambulance)));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}


private void getDriverInfo(){
    mDriverInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID);
    mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                if(dataSnapshot.child("Name")!=null){
                    mDriverName.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue()).toString());
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.child("Phone")!=null){
                    mDriverPhone.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("Phone").getValue()).toString());
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.child("Car")!=null){
                    mDriverCar.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("Car").getValue()).toString());
                }

                int ratingSum = 0;
                float ratingsTotal = 0;
                float ratingsAvg = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child("rating").getChildren()){
                    ratingSum = ratingSum + Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(child.getValue()).toString());
                    ratingsTotal++;
                }
                if(ratingsTotal!= 0){
                    ratingsAvg = ratingSum/ratingsTotal;
                    mRatingBar.setRating(ratingsAvg);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        }else{
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}

LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {

            mLastLocation = location;

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

            if(!getDriversAroundStarted)
                getDriversAround();

        }
    }

};

boolean getDriversAroundStarted = false;
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
private void getDriversAround(){
    getDriversAroundStarted = true;
    DatabaseReference driverLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("driversAvailable");

    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(driverLocation);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLongitude(), mLastLocation.getLatitude()), 999999999);

    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {



            LatLng driverLocation = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);

            Marker mDriverMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLocation).title(key).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ambulance)));
            mDriverMarker.setTag(key);

            markers.add(mDriverMarker);

            for(Marker markerIt : markers){
                if(markerIt.getTag().equals(key))
                    return;
            }





        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
            for(Marker markerIt : markers){
                if(markerIt.getTag().equals(key)){
                    markerIt.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            for(Marker markerIt : markers){
                if(markerIt.getTag().equals(key)){
                    markerIt.setPosition(new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
            new  android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Please give permission...")
                    .setMessage("Please give permission...")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CustomerMapActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);

                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
        else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CustomerMapActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);

        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide the permission...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }


    }}

private DatabaseReference driveHasEndedRef;
private ValueEventListener driveHasEndedRefListener;
private void getHasRideEnded(){
    // String driverId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    driveHasEndedRef  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID).child("customerRequest").child("customerRideId");
    driveHasEndedRefListener = driveHasEndedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){


            }else{

                endRide();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
private void endRide()
{

    requestBol = false;
    if(geoQuery != null){
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    }
    if(driverLocationRefListener != null&& driveHasEndedRefListener != null){
        driverLocationRef.removeEventListener(driverLocationRefListener);
        driveHasEndedRef.removeEventListener(driveHasEndedRefListener);
    }


    if(driverFoundID!=null){
        DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID).child("customerRequest");
        driverRef.removeValue();
        driverFoundID = null;

    }
    driverFound = false;
    radius = 1;

    String userId=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customerRequest");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    geoFire.removeLocation(userId);
    if( pickupMarker!=null){
        pickupMarker.remove();
    }
    if (mDriverMarker != null){
        mDriverMarker.remove();
    }
    mRequest.setText("Request An Ambulance");

    mDriverInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mDriverName.setText("");
    mDriverPhone.setText("");

}
```

}`

Comment: "due to many errors or no responses" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, if you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600 (six hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.